# MP3 doesn't play when I press stream

Tags: java, android, mp3

I am trying to play a MP3 from a stream but the issue is after I press play it would automatically play. Also the play button doesn't play the audio it just sets it to stream. How can I make my MP3 automatically play?

```
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url); 
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

                if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                }else {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                }

                primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
            }
    }});

    sb.setMax(99);
    sb.setOnTouchListener(this);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}

private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
    sb.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds)*100));
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
    }
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.progress_bar){
        /** Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer to seekBar primary progress position*/
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
            int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100) * sb.getProgress();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);

    mediaPlayer.stop();
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    sb.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
}
   }
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I click play and I see my seekbar filling up but it wont play.

I also get this message:

```
E/MediaPlayer(28985): stop called in state 0 E/MediaPlayer(28985):
error (-38, 0) E/MediaPlayer(28985): Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer(28985): stop called in state 0 E/MediaPlayer(28985):
error (-38, 0) E/MediaPlayer(28985): Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer(28985): stop called in state 0 E/MediaPlayer(28985):
error (-38, 0) E/MediaPlayer(28985): Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer(28985): stop called in state 0 E/MediaPlayer(28985):
error (-38, 0) E/MediaPlayer(28985): Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer(28985): stop called in state 0 E/MediaPlayer(28985):
error (-38, 0) E/MediaPlayer(28985): Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer(28985): stop called in state 0 E/MediaPlayer(28985):
error (-38, 0) E/MediaPlayer(28985): Error (-38,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to implement `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener`. Since you are using `prepareAsync()`, you need to wait until the MediaPlayer is prepared before you can call `start()`. When you get the `onPrepared()` callback, at that point it's safe to call the `start()` method.

Comment: I've tried that but all I get is: E/MediaPlayer(28985): stop called in state 0 E/MediaPlayer(28985):
error (-38, 0) E/MediaPlayer(28985): Error (-38,0) spammed and it doesnt play

Comment: didn't work so I just coded my own async and use prepare instead of async